# Unsatisfied Bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

My bounty on [Coating Every Pancake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38226/coating-every-pancake) expires shortly but no one has answered the question in the [Pancake Stack language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pancake_Stack) which was the goal of the bounty.

Should I just let the bounty run out and award it to the best existing answer? Can I request an extension? Are there other options?

Comment: I was distracted by all the unnecessary `global` statements in the implementation. You don't need it where you are mutating a variable. only when it is rebound

Comment: For the record, I tried, but the fact that it's impossible to reach the third element of the stack or below without modifying the top two items makes this quite difficult!

Comment: @gnibbler Sorry about that. I just threw it together in about 2 hours coding on a Saturday. Just for fun. I didn't really care that much about if I was doing it completely right. I thought that the `global` statements were necessary, however. Now I know better. Thanks.

Comment: @gnibbler There: http://ideone.com/h0Nxst . I didn't replace the link in the esolang page, because Calvin's Hobbies created a link for his/her bounty.

Comment: @Quincunx, you still need the ones for the rebinding of variables. eg `line = `. Otherwise a local variable is created instead. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @gnibbler Those two places are the only places where that's needed. Sorry for not thinking about it.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat; I've got a bounty expiring where the only answer is by me as a community answer.  :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/13) for more information. To answer your specifics:

- Bounties cannot be extended.
- You can award the bounty to any answer that you didn't write yourself.
- If you don't award the bounty, and there is an answer written *after* the bounty started that has a score of 2 or more, that answer is auto-awarded half the bounty.

  - If there is more than one such answer, then the answer with the highest score is auto-awarded, with ties broken by earliest posting date.